# Looking for OCR software to extract heading, sub-heading and date from scanned image files

Tags: file-management, ocr, image-recognition, image, rename

I have scanned in 100s of documents and want to organise them into an existing folder structure.

To do this I want to determine the heading/title and sub-heading and any date in the scanned image files.

I need do this in a batch, to 100s of files. I want to rename them with the date, heading and subheading and retain the original filename e.g. `IMG0001.jpg` as a suffix to make each file unique.

What software can do this?

## Research so far

### full solution

this seems close - full program solution

https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9mvkt2tfp9tp?hl=en-us&gl=US

also these - but way out of my price range:

- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/78174/9175
- [APIs to extract numbers from images?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/77713/apis-to-extract-numbers-from-images)

### coding examples

Rename based on description of image, more visual object based rather than text.

https://hackaday.com/2023/12/29/using-local-ai-on-the-command-line-to-rename-images-and-more/

https://github.com/sanjujosh/auto-image-renamer?tab=readme-ov-file

Separating out headings -  potentially expensive solution given as answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320121/how-to-separate-title-and-headers-from-body-text-in-image

[Looking for a library that extracts text from images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/62495/looking-for-a-library-that-extracts-text-from-images)

OCR cloud solutions:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/products/ai-services/ai-vision/

https://aws.amazon.com/pm/textract/

Discussion of coding examples:

https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-ocr/c/rRXmMYhT7j4?pli=1

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/15hwpoq/pytesseract_ocr_can_you_filter_down_the_text_it/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831612/getting-the-bounding-box-of-the-recognized-words-using-python-tesseract